# Angular with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm hoping to create an app with using Angular, Also hope add lots of jquery animations + Jquery UI (eg: jquery animate, fadeIn, fadeOut,.. etc) , Soo Is it possible to use Jquery functions along with angular.

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq

Comment: Hello, as stated by @NidhishKrishnan, even if you can make jQuery and Angular work together, you *really* have to think differently when using Angular. I think when you want to do something with jQuery, there are 99% of chance that you should do it in Angular (or in a directive).

Comment: Hey I found a way and now I'm using angular with ionic and its solve my animation problem also. Please remove this [closed] coz I can't ask question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AngularJS` is here to be built for robust arhitecture and that is why we see so many modules in terms of directives and other components. Putting `JQuery` with it will be like going away from their core design and you will yourself end up in a mess maintaining the codebase.

**jQuery is a crutch if you are writing AngularJS applications.**

If you’re starting an `AngularJS` app, take a good look at [ng-boilerplate](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp). Then take a look at [ui-bootstrap’s directives](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src). They are a living example of how you can do “jQuery things” with a fraction of the code, and build an app that is easier to maintain, way more testable, and generally nicer to work with.

Take a look at this stuff

- **[How do I “think in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)** - An excellent Stack Overflow post that expands on this viewpoint
- [**Using AngularJS? Then stop using jQuery**](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/07/27/using-angularjs-stop-using-jquery-as-a-crutch/)

Comment: +1 for linking that other SO question.

Answer (score 3):

"Does Angular use the jQuery library?
Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.

Due to a change to use on()/off() rather than bind()/unbind(), Angular 1.2 only operates with jQuery 1.7.1 or above."